# Count points below and above in point of intersection of two graphs

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

[image: Graph with data and limits]

Hi all,
I'm wondering maybe someone can help me...Basically  I have two graphs ("data" black one and "limit" red one). What I have to do is to calculate the count of points above and below red line. Does anybody know how to do that with nvd3 / d3?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need D3 for this -- just iterate through your array of data points and count.

Comment: Hm, but do I have to find intersection points to do that?

Comment: No, you just need the absolute values.

Comment: `var values = [{
  x: 1,
  y: 1.5
}, {
  x: 1.5,
  y: 2
}, {
  x: 3,
  y: 3
}, {
  x: 4.5,
  y: 1.75
}, {
  x: 5,
  y: 8
}, {
  x: 5.5,
  y: 3
}, ];

var greenAboveLimit = 0;

var limits = [{
  x: 4,
  y: 6
}, {
  x: 7,
  y: 6
}];

var isAbove = function (values, limits) {
    return values.x > limits.x && values.y > limits.y;

};

for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < limits.length; j++) {
        if (isAbove(values[i],limits[j])) {
            greenAboveLimit++;
        }

    }
  }

alert(greenAboveLimit);`

Something like this, I think I got it...Thanks